# More compelling alternative to the cylinder icon to illustrate a database for end-users?

Tags: database, icons, visualization

I have to give presentations to end-users about technical topics and one of the questions I have occasionally been asked is why I use a cylinder icon to represent a database. I don't have a good answer for this except that this is the way databases are usually represented in technical literature and, since I'm not an artist, I haven't been able to come up with anything better.

But I'm wondering if anyone has seen any more compelling alternatives to this traditional approach for representing a database visually or could provide any suggestions?

[image]
<sub>(source: [www.gsf.fi](http://www.gsf.fi/nupulse/images/database.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I believe the cylinder derives from the idea of a HDD or a stack of platters.

For non-technical users, maybe a picture of a computer or filing cabinets would be more understandable.

Comment: +1 for cabinet. cabinet is the most logical picture that can represent database.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider what the user is going to have in the database, if the client is going to use it for photos, maybe make it a stack of Polaroids, or a photo album, really the idea of the cylinder is like a hard disk, but the conceptual idea of a database can relate to whatever will be stored in it.

Be as descriptive as you can for you clients to know what they might find there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps several images could be layered - an image, a list, an internet icon - to suggest the contents of a database.